# Not able to install Visual Studio 2017 Professional nor make VS 2019 work correctly

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I am able to succesfully install/uninstall Visual Studio 2019 but not 2017. Please see the attached screenshot.

[image: VS Professional 2017 installation error]

I have tried the following on my Windows 10 remote desktop machine:

> 1. Remove the contents of C:\Users(useraccountid)\AppData\Local\Temp and try to install VS Pro 2017
> 2. Uninstall VS Professional 2019 and also Remove the folder and contents of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019 and
>    try to install VS Pro 2017
> 3. Shut down all programs and try to install  VS Pro 2017 but it will not move past the error message.

The issue with VS Professional 2019 is also attached in the second screenshot.

[image: VS Professional 2019 Framework Error]

Comment: For the VS 2017 installation, please go to the folder: %ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_Instances and remove those sub folders to other places, go to the Visual Studio installation folder (normally under %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio) and delete the folder '2017', after that, make sure window update is up-to-date, clear %temp% folder and disable any antivirus software, reboot the computer and run the VS 2017 installer as administrator. For the VS 2019, if you create a new C# console .NET Framework project, can you select the .NET Framework 4 as target framework?

Comment: Hi, just want to check if your issue is solved or not? If you have any updates, please feel free to let us know.